# Adding bracelines to a dropdown navbar

Tags: java, html, css

Hey guys I've gotten stuck trying to add brace lines to my nav bar that has a dropdown menu with it. I want to get this sorted out before I move on with everything else. I'm also having trouble getting the dropdown content to stay below the dropdown topic section. For example if I select the "Cameras" tab in the History dropdown and I want to select the "Pioneers" tab the dropdown box covers up the History dropdown and I want that to stay underneath the History dropdown like it does when you first hover over History.

Here is my Homepage HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Film History</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="theTopnav">
  <a  class="current" href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">History
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="camerahistory.html">Cameras</a>
        <a href="camerapioneers.html">Pioneers</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Science
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="camerascience.html">Cameras</a>
      <a href="developmentscience.html">Development</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theTopnav.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Camera History HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Film History</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="theTopnav">
  <a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="current" button class="dropbtn">History
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="camerahistory.html">Cameras</a>
        <a href="camerapioneers">Pioneers</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Science
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Development</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theTopnav.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
.topnav .current {
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn{
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss marked a `button` as an `a` in your HTML on the camera code in the current section. So I changed the `a` to `button` and it solved most of your problems, but I also moved some CSS code to the "current" of the CSS section so it highlights what is current.  check it out.

```css
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
.topnav .current {
  color: #f4fd68;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn{
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #f4fd68;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Film History</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="theTopnav">
  <a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="current" button class="dropbtn">History
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="camerahistory.html">Cameras</a>
        <a href="camerapioneers">Pioneers</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Science
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Test</a>
      <a href="#">Development</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theTopnav.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That helps a ton! Thank you so much, now I have to figure out how to add brace lines between the Home and History.

Comment: Glad it helped,  but sorry for my understanding, can you please explain what a "brace line" is? Maybe I can help

Comment: Home | History | Science

Comment: Oh that's easy. Add this to your CSS styles: `.dropdown *{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}`

Comment: Or better yet, maybe this! `.dropdown > * :not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}`

Comment: The second one you provided is exactly the one I needed, but now I'm trying to add those same lines between the home, history and science. Like this    Home | History | Science

And I'm trying to add a logo to the nav bar and keep that to the left side of the screen while keeping the nav to the right but still have it all be responsive.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked! please consider selecting me as your answer if everything is solved :).

Comment: Is there a way to add an image to this forum so you can see what I'm seeing?

Comment: I think you need a certain reputation points to add an image, but if you upload to something like imgur.com you can post the link and I can see.

Comment: Great! that's what you want right? Also, my second code should remove that bottom line in the menu correct?

Comment: I'm trying to get vertical lines between the 3 options in the nav bar and the Film History logo shoved to the left side but still in the nave bar and still have it responsive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213926/discussion-between-geesegoose-and-john).

Comment: oh sure. add `border-left: 1px solid #ccc;` to `.dropdown` CSS